# Могу ли я менять местами столбцы на графике?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, static-analysis

Есть фрейм данных со списком штрафов. Я построил countplot. Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы столбцы располагались по убыванию кол-во нарушений?

В данном примере порядок столбцов предполагаю: Speeding, Moving violation, Equipment, Other ...

Данные:
https://www.kaggle.com/melihkanbay/police

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/egormartynov/Documents/DataSets/police.csv")
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(12,6)})
sns.countplot(data = df, x="violation", palette="viridis", hue="driver_gender")
```

Comment: Да, можете, разумеется.

Comment: @strawdog, подскажите, пожалуйста, как?

Comment: Егор, как же я вам подскажу, если вы не привели код в воспроизводимом виде, и самое главное, данные в таком виде, чтобы я мог их использовать. Мало того, что это идёт вразрез с правилами, так еще и показывать лучше на примере, чем теорию объяснять, да?

Comment: обновил вопрос, извините за неточную формулировку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [`order=<lists of strings>`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

```
sns.countplot(..., order=df["violation"].value_counts().index)
```

PS в будущем советую оформлять вопросы в соответствии с [этими рекомендациями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/).